# Passing down async fetched data via Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-context

The data is not displaying in the child component `Store`. In the `Store`component, the `console.log` in the `useEffect()` hook returns `undefined`. I suspect the reason being that the `fetchAPI` function in the parent component is only called after `myContext.Provider` is rendered, thus the `value` of `myContext.Provider` is undefined.

How can I pass the `data`(hook state) I fetched from the API in `Stores`(parent) down to `Store`(child) in this case?

```
export const myContext = createContext()


const Stores = () =>{

    const [data, setData ] = useState([])


    const fetchAPI = async() => {
        var res = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/store/get')
        var result = await res.json()
        var final= result.map(item => item)
        setData(final)
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        fetchAPI().then(console.log(data))
    }, [data])

    return(
        <div>
         <myContext.Provider value={data} > 
            {data.map(item => {
                return(
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <Link to={`stores/${item.itemId}`}><li>{item.item.name}</li></Link>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                )
            })}
          </myContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
};
```

```
const Store = () => {

    const specific = useContext(myContext)

    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log(specific)
        }

    )
    
    return(
    <>
    {specific.map( item => {
        return(
        <div>
            <h2> Description: {item.name}</h2>
        </div>
        )
    })}
    </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Well first of all, `then` expects a function but you're passing it the result of a console log, which is undefined since console log doesn't return anything. And the reason you're not seeing data being populated is because the component hasn't re-rendered yet. You're closing around the data variable, which at the time of closure is an empty array. You're also going to have an infinite loop, because you are calling fetch every time data changes, and you set data inside the fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use fetch api isn't correct I think. `fetch` returns a promise, so you need to return the promise in your fetchAPI method if you want to uses `.then()`.

`.then()` allow you to grab the promise and work with it, here is your code changed to work:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const myContext = createContext()

const App = () =>{

    const [data, setData ] = useState([]);


    const fetchAPI = () => {
      // It return a promise
       return fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/store/get');
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        fetchAPI().then(data => 
        // try to call .json() method. this method returns a promise
          data.json().then(json => {
            // if .json() succeed, then do your stuff
            console.log(json);
            setData(json.data.map(item => item));
          })
        )
        // if .json() fails, promise is rejected with your error
        .then(err => console.log('err', err));
    }, []); // empty array to prevent looping (rule : do not update a state you are passing in this deps array)

    return(
        <div>
         <myContext.Provider value={data} > 
            {data.map(item => {
                return(
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><pre>{JSON.stringify(item)}</pre></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                )
            })}
          </myContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is [the repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x9iiga?file=index.js).